# Is it possible to identify the mechanism or algorithm that generates numbers having a list of matches and a list of mismatches

Tags: algorithm, random, number-theory

Dear stackoverflow community,

I thank in advance for your comments.

This example is fictional:
I want to draw a random sample of students based on their matriculation number. Let's assume that universities do not assign matriculation numbers continuously but randomly. Furthermore, let's assume that these matriculation numbers have 7 digits and each matriculation number is unique, e.g. 0000001.

I know e.g. that the numbers 
0000001, 0000020, 0004000, 0000050, 0600000, 7000000, 0000008 and 0001000
 are **not assigned** to any student (*mismatch list*).

I know, however, that the numbers 0030000 and 0900000 **are assigned** to somebody (*match list*).

Now I want to draw a random sample of students (with valid assigned matriculation numbers) that is larger than my list of two by pseudo-randomly **generating assigned matriculation numbers**. Without adding any information, a number generator would generate more matriculation numbers that are unassigned compared to those being assigned (namely to a share of all possible combinations of digits minus the total amount of students/total amount of students).

Given that I have large lists of assigned and unassigned numbers, can I use that information to avoid that my number generator generates matriculation numbers that are not assigned?
And if that is not possible, can I use the information to improve the prediction/share of generated assigned matriculation numbers?

Initially I was thinking of reconstructing the algorithm that assings matriculation numbers to students based on a large number of observations of assigned and unassigned numbers. But a reduction of generating unassigned matriculation numbers would also help.

Thank you and best wishes!

Comment: (1) it seems like there should be 10^7 or 9*10^6 seven-digit numbers, depending on whether zeroes are allowed or not; (2) to get a pseudorandom k-subset of the 100 assigned numbers, it seems shuffling and taking the first k entries would work; (3) are you asking, given a set of 100 seven-digit numbers, to determine the most compact representation of those numbers, or some set of numbers including (most of) those numbers (and maybe some others)?

Comment: Can't make sense of this question. Can you provide an example ?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I edited the question with a hopefully more comprehensive example. I want to generate pseudo-randomly assigned matriculation numbers that are not on the list of those numbers I already know. I hope that having information about numbers that are not assigned and having information about numbers that are assigned can help me to avoid pseudo-random generations of numbers not being assigned to students.